# How to disable automatic minimize window when clicking outside of this window? I'm using Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: window-manager, xubuntu

When I have, for example,browser open and it is maximized then open terminal window not maximized I want to keep terminal window open when I click anywhere on browser. How to do this? So far when clicking on browser the terminal window minimize to panel. I know the keys ALT-TAB switch windows.Thanks.My system is xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have any screenshots? Normally whatever window is active is in front, If the browser's full screen/maximized, the terminal would move in front of it if you switch to it... you want the terminal always on top even if the browser is active?

Comment: @Xen2050 yes l want the terminal always on top even if the browser is active! Note: terminal and browser are only examples, should be any program on maximized window and any program on minimized window. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want the terminal window always on top, there's an option for that in the window's menu (ALT-space or right click on the menu bar). The "Always on Top" entry is available in every program's window I've checked.

[image]

Comment: this is a solution only for terminal window, and for any others  programs ? thanks

Comment: It works for every program with a window I've tried, Web browsers, Thunar, text editors, Disks... Just check the ALT-Space or right click menu

Comment: Many thanks, just this alt-space solved my request!

Comment: @vladimirpavloski You're welcome :) An upvote / up arrow & correct / check-mark is a good way to say "thanks", stackexchange is actually a little anti-social since they don't like really like "thanks" messages...